# How do I get the last modified date of a directory?

Tags: perl, date, timestamp, last-modified

I'm using 5.16.3.  How do I get the last modified timestamp of a directory?  With a file, I can run

```
    my $deployFile = "$jbossHome/standalone/deployments/$artifactId.$packaging";
    open my $fh, '>', $deployFile or die("File does not exist.");
    my $mtime = (stat ($fh))[9];
```

I tried this logic with a directory,

```
my $mtime = stat("$jbossHome/standalone/deployments/$artifactId.$packaging");
```

but the result is always

```
Thu Jan  1 00:00:01 1970
```

even though I can tell on the server that the last modified time stamp of the directory is this weekend.

Comment: No, you need `my $mtime = (stat("$jbossHome/standalone/deployments/$artifactId.$packaging"))[9];` - see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html . Also, you're not checking a directory, you're checking the same string as above.

Comment: um, are you sure that you get what you show, that (epoch's) timestamp in scalar context?  With `my $v = stat(...);` you should get a mere success/failure boolean (1 or `''`).

Comment: @zdim there's definitely some code in between, perhaps a `localtime($mtime)`

Comment: @Grinnz Yeah, and that should be in the question, what I meant to bring up; why should we have to guess? Also, as Corion noted, they are using the same string in both samples. (What else may be missing or wrong?)

Comment: @Dave I don't mean to be rough on you but i do mean to suggest to be careful when writing and posting questions. This one's easy and you got good answers but with more complicated stuff an imprecise question usually makes it far harder to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This :

```
my $mtime = stat("$jbossHome/standalone/deployments/$artifactId.$packaging");
```

Should be written as :

```
my $mtime = (stat("$jbossHome/standalone/deployments/$artifactId.$packaging"))[9];
```

See [perldoc stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html).

> **stat EXPR** returns a 13-element list giving the status info for a file, either the file opened via FILEHANDLE or DIRHANDLE, or named by EXPR.

In the resulting list, mtime in 10th position (index 9).

And also :

> In scalar context, stat returns a boolean value indicating success or failure

So in your code, where you evaluate in scalar context, the mtime variable is assigned a value of 1. When interpretef as a Unix timestamp, this means  1 second after January 1st, 1970.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the core [File::stat](https://perldoc.pl/File::stat) to get a much nicer interface to the stat fields.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::stat;
my $stat = stat($filename) or die "stat $filename failed: $!";
my $mtime = $stat->mtime;
```